# What advantages do GraphQL Subscriptions offer over NestJS Gateway for pushing server-to-client events using 'ws'?

Tags: websocket, graphql, nestjs, graphql-subscriptions

Why do we need GraphQL Subscriptions instead of NestJS Gateway both using `ws`?

What's the difference in between the two in achieving the common goal i.e.

> Pushing events from Server to Client

I've tried finding the answer but haven't been able to find the real advantage in using GraphQL Subscriptions over NestJS Gateways.